# How can I get the foreign field's name in queryset?

Tags: python, django

I have a Disk model, which has three ForeignKey:

```
class Disk(models.Model):
    diskEssenceType = models.ForeignKey(to=DiskEssenceType, related_name='disks')  #  "SAS", "SSD" 等
    diskOsType = models.ForeignKey(to=DiskOSType, related_name='disks') # "系统盘" "数据盘" 两种选择
    hostType = models.ForeignKey(to=HostType, related_name='disks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)  # 单价

    def __str__(self):
        return self.diskEssenceType.name + "-" + self.hostType.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.diskEssenceType.name + "-" + self.hostType.name
```

I use queryset :

```
qs = Disk.objects.filter(hostType=obj)
```

Its queryset data is like bellow, after use `model_to_dict` convert:

```
{
   "price": 5.0,
   "diskOsType": 1,
   "hostType": 6,
   "diskEssenceType": 1,
   "id": 4
   },
```

But I want to get the `diskEssenceType`'s name, and the `diskOsType`'s name, not its id, how to do with that?

---

This is the reason why I use the `model_to_dict`:

[<Disk: > is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350450/disk-is-not-json-serializable)

---

My model have **unicode** method:

```
class DiskEssenceType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=8, default="SSD")  # "SAS", "SSD" 等
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You shouldn't really use model_to_dict, that's an internal function. Why exactly do you need a dict?

Comment: @DanielRoseman See my this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350450/disk-is-not-json-serializable

Comment: That's a terrible answer. It bypasses the whole point of serializers.

Comment: How to do with that? I want to get the name, not the id in my serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You need in your models to define :

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.<you return>)
```

then you need in your model `hostType` to define that:

```
class hostType(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, default="myname")

     def __unicode__(self):
          return unicode(self.name)
```

then when you make queryset you get this:

```
qs = Disk.objects.filter(hostType=obj)


{
   "price": 5.0,
   "diskOsType": 1,
   "hostType": "my name",
   "diskEssenceType": 1,
   "id": 4
   },
```

Comment: @EdwinCubillos no. Neither of those lines have anything to do with this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, yes you're  right,  but i don`t for that i ask for the python version